# how to pass access token and refresh token to header in retrofit kotlin in koin

Tags: android, kotlin, authentication, retrofit, koin

I am developing new android app where I am making post login request but I have confused I am using koin dependcy injection how can I pass refresh token and access token after successfully response. in order to making a call

```
interface MeloApi {

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("/login")
    suspend fun makeLogin(@Body loginModel: LoginModel) : Response<LoginModel>



}
```

below my login model
data class LoginModel(val username:String, val password:String)

// following my base url

```
object Constants {

        const val BASE_URL = "https://api.getmelo.app/"

    }
```

when I making post  request in the body I am sending following format

{
"username": "username",
"password": "password"
}

and it is returning
following format

```
{
    "refreshToken": "refreshtoken",
    "accessToken": "accesstoken",
    "status": "success",
    "user": {
        "username": "username",
        "email": "email",
        "id": "5E038B1F-BE2F-477B-9E87-69411D0D622B",
        "kind": "adult",
        "details": {
            "firstName": "Test",
            "lastName": "User",
            "id": "12DEA70B-1146-46D3-A57B-B47730BC8C4B"
        },
        "status": "active"
    }
}
```

below my networkModule.kt class where I want to pass refresh token and access token

```
val appModule = module {
        single {
            val httpInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            httpInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

            Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(
                    OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .addInterceptor()
                        .addInterceptor(httpInterceptor).build()
                )
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build()
                .create(MeloApi::class.java)
        }


}
```

My question is how can I pass refresh token and access token in header my network koin module

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a mistake in your request definition.

```
suspend fun makeLogin(@Body loginModel: LoginModel) : Response<LoginModel>
```

According to the JSON response you posted, you are not getting `LoginModel` as response, but rather a model with `accessToken` and `refreshToken`. Let's name it:

```
data class AuthTokenEntity(
    val accessToken: String,
    val refreshToken: String,
    // the rest of the model according to the JSON
)
```

So change your `makeLogin` to:

```
suspend fun makeLogin(@Body loginModel: LoginModel) : AuthTokenEntity
```

Now, I assume you are trying to implement the OAuth flow, and you store the tokens locally (either DB or SharedPreferences). To pass access token to your requests, create an `Interceptor` that attaches the authorization header with the access token to each outgoing request. Check my [example](https://github.com/phamtdat/Android-koin-and-oauth-snippets/blob/main/AuthInterceptor.kt).

Now, if it's really OAuth that you are implementing, I am quite sure there is a different request to refresh an expired access token. You use the refresh token for that request only, you don't pass refresh token to any other requests. If I am right, you'll have to add a new method into your `MeloApi` (the parameter type depends on the request's definition):

```
suspend fun refreshToken(refreshToken: String) : AuthTokenEntity
```

Then, you need to create an `Authenticator` that will call `refreshToken` in case the access token expires and server returns HTTP 401. Check my [example](https://github.com/phamtdat/Android-koin-and-oauth-snippets/blob/main/TokenAuthenticator.kt)

Finally, you provide the `Interceptor` and the `Authenticator` to your `Retrofit` via `Koin` as follow:

```
val appModule = module {

    single { MyAuthenticator() }
    factory { MyInterceptor() }
    
    single {
        val httpInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        httpInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

        Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(
                OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(httpInterceptor)
                    .addInterceptor(get<MyInterceptor>())
                    .authenticator(get<MyAuthenticator>())
                    .build()
            )
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .build()
            .create(MeloApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

For more comprehensive examples, check the [snippets](https://github.com/phamtdat/Android-koin-and-oauth-snippets) I created for this question.

Comment: thank you for your answer I dont have add extra paramater in my makeLogin post method?

Comment: I don't know, I don't see inside your API. Did you test out the `makeLogin` if it works? Usually email and password is enough. You may need to add the @FormUrlEncoded annotation to you @POST methods.